# Is "MUL" an acceptable "Primary Key"?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to use the `ActiveUUID` gem to make the primary key for my `Survey` table to be a UUID. (MySQL)

Even though I have `:primary_key => true` it still is setting it to `MUL` for some reason? Is this expected?

Migration:

```
class CreateSurveys < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :surveys, :id => false do |t|
      t.references :employee, :null => false

      t.uuid :id, :primary_key => true
      t.datetime :expired_at

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :surveys, :id
  end
end
```

Model: survey.rb

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base

  include ActiveUUID::UUID

  belongs_to :employee

  validates :employee, :presence => true  

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer. I needed to remove `add_index :surveys, :id`. Apparently a primary key is already indexed. That fixed it